# jna: pass a string from C# to Java

Tags: jna

I am using Unamanged dependencies (RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport) and jna in a small C# function that should return a string consumed within another now java function.

Following the jna suggestions for mapping  i crafted the code below:

My C# code:

```
[RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport]
public static unsafe char* Test(string id)
{
  unsafe
  {
      fixed (char *s = "test passed")
          {
              return s;
           }
       }    
 }
```

Java side:

```
public interface ITest extends Library{

    public String Test(String id);
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

 ITest nativeExample= (ITest)Native.loadLibrary("C:/native/JavaLib.dll", ITest.class);
  String s = nativeExample.Test("id");
  System.out.println(s);
 }
```

So, all that is printed, is '**t**', because I bet all is being transmitted is the address to s[0].
Has anyone had luck mapping strings from C# to java through jna?

Plain strings in the C# code throws errors.

Comment: Generally you do *not* want to return a string, unless the caller owns the memory, or you run the risk of leaking memory from the native code.  If you don't understand the ramifications of returning a string, you should instead have the caller pass in a buffer and have the native function populate that buffer with the desired information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried returning a string instead of char? or changing char *s to char s[]

Comment: so, this is the first thing I tried:           [RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExport]
        public static unsafe string Test2(string id)
        {
            return "Test passed"+id;

        } And I don't know what I mingled. Tried it again just now, and it works! I guess I had to post :P to make it work. Thanks!!!